# bounding the measure of a disjoint union under a product measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(X\times Y,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space such that $P$
is a product measure on $X\times Y$.
Let $E=\cup_{x\in X}E_x$ be an event such that: (i) for each $x\in X$,
$E_x$ is an event of the form $\{x\}\times B_x$, for some $B_x\subseteq Y$, and (ii) the marginal probability of $B_x$ is at least $\frac{1}{2}$. Is it the case that also $P(E)\geq\frac{1}{2}$?

For discrete probability spaces the answer is yes and the proof is straight forward. I think it should also hold in general but I am having difficulties in finding a proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your assumption is saying is that the section

$$
E^{(x)}=\{y \mid (x,y)\in E\}
$$
is given by $E^{(x)}=E_x$.

Now, your prblem states that $P=P_1\times P_2$ is some product measure, so that we can use the Fubini-Tonelli theorem on the indicator function $1_E$ to conclude

$$
P(E)=\int 1_E (x,y) dP(x,y) =\int \int 1_E(x,y)dP_2(y) dP_1(x)=\int P_2 (E_x) dP_1(x) \geq \int 1/2 dP_1(x)=1/2. 
$$